# Right shift key not working with 'q'

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

It's only the 'q' key that's not working with right shift, the left shift seems to be working fine with it. When I press q key while holding down the right shift, nothing prints on the screen. I tried other key combinations with right shift, the whole set of keys i.e alphabets and number keys are all working fine. It's a really strange behaviour, as it's only a single key combination. I'm using Windows 8.1  now. Any ideas what might be causing this and how possibly I could go about fixing it? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it is reserved for some other functionality may be. Do you use any keyboard mapping tools

Comment: No I don't know much about these things, so I can safely say I don't use them.

Comment: Can you try a different keyboard, just to confirm the issue is with keyboard or not

Comment: I tried a USB keyboard a few days ago, and that seemed to worked fine with my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one possible explanation. It has to do with 'keyboard regional settings' and it comes to mind because I had dealt with a similar problem some time ago.

But... We'll get into that in a bit. First, let's try to make sure that "rshift+q" isn't as badly nerfed as we might be suspecting...

**Idea#1**

♦♦♦♦♦♦

Specifically, let's see if the "rShift+q" keystroke combination still seems to be nerfed if you restart Windows into DOS mode (aka, 'Command Prompt Mode').

All the information I'm posting here in the form of screenshots is copied from http://www.startupsmart.com.au/technology/something-to-try-if-windows-8-stops-working/2013120311292.html and from http://www.startupsmart.com.au/technology/how-to-boot-windows-8-or-81-into-a-dos-style-command-prompt/2014011011475.html

[image: how to boot into safe mode dos command prompt on windows 8.1]

Now that you're in DOS mode... Test to see if "rShift + q" is still nerfed.

**Idea#2**

♦♦♦♦♦♦

If not... then I have a good suspicion that your problem has to do with regional settings.

If memory serves right, while I was traveling a couple of summers ago, I had leant my laptop to a guy from Austria. Because his English wasn't that great, he needed to change the language settings for the laptop's keyboard.

Needless to say, he changed it back later.

However, when I took the laptop home with me, for weeks I would have a problem with my keyboard where maybe 5% of the time, certain things wouldn't come out on the screen as I thought I typed them, if they would get detected at all.

What I ended up discovering was that there was a 'hotkey combination', that would automatically switch the keyboard-setting to the foreign-setting for German, which was enabled on the laptop.

I disabled the hotkey, and things worked fine.

Since I don't have Windows 8.1, I can't speak to how to do this specifically, but you might want to consider exploring your system to find the setting.

**Idea#3**

♦♦♦♦♦♦

Ah, and lastly... If all else fails, there's a program that might help you determine if "rShift+q" is registered as a hotkey by some program on your computer.

It's Hotkey Commander, available at http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/ .

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for such an informative post MercWithMouth, I tried your suggestions,first with HotKey commander software, I couldn't find a hot-key reserved for rShift+q in it. Then I went in to advanced settings and then command prompt to see if it was a regional-keyboard settings issue, but again it wasn't the case, Q couldn't be printed with rShift, all the all keys and key combinations worked just fine as they're Windows. I can't think it's a bad key, either q or rShift, because normal q key is working and Q could be typed with lShift, while rShift is working with the rest of the keys except for q

Comment: Sorry that was probably not very nice of me, I've given it +1 now. :)

Comment: >Then I went in to advanced settings and then command prompt to see if it was a regional-keyboard settings issue... Hmmm. No, that was a totally separate suggestion. Errr... specfiically, did you RESTART IN DOS MODE to test what rshift+q does when you're in there? Let me know

Comment: Yes, in Windows 8.1 you can access the advanced settings through charm-bar and then the Windows performs a restart and starts in DOS mode, from there you can make changes to the System. I did just that, and the q key didn't work with rShift there either. I can't understand what the issue is! q+rShift, that's all, that's not working, all the other keys are working fine.

Comment: @AndySemyonov Yikes. Yeah, it does seem like some sort of keyboard issue. Maybe some sort of quasi-short-circuit within the keyboard? Possibly one caused by spilling a bit of coffee on the keyboard? At this venture, you should try plugging the keyboard into a separate keyboard to see if it acts up there, too. Similarly, also try plugging in a keyboard from another keyboard that works fine and see if it works on your computer. If it's really physical damage, you might consider getting a new keyboard (or not, since it's only 'Q'). I'd recommend the Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 3000 v2.0 myself.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply again, I'm absolutely sure that I never spilled any liquid on the keyboard, it's still very clean, almost new. It has to be physical damage, although I can't understand how that's possible with only affecting one key combination in the entire keyboard. :) If other keys, or key combinations start failing soon, I'll consider getting a new keyboard. On another note, I can''t help feeling that some Windows update might have had smth to do with it, because the problem started after that. I'll be getting Win 10 soon, so will be interested to see if the problem persists there too.

Comment: @AndySemyonov did you try plugging it into a different computer yet? or a different keyboard into the computer you're on now?

Comment: Well the laptop that I have is of a very rare model (HCL ME(2025)), I don't see many ppl using it, that's why it's another problem getting a replacement keyboard for it. I had asked a computers dealer to look for one, he said he couldn't find an original but was able to get a duplicate one; it looked a very flimsy make, anyway, it fitted nicely on the laptop, but when I turned on the Windows, the keys were all out of sorts, some were printing but most not, it was surely not compatible.

Comment: Ah, so it's a LAPTOP keyboard. That could be a slightly different issue then. If the one keystroke combination is bothering you, then you might just want to use an external keyboard. That's what I do with my laptop, anyway. I never much cared for laptop keyboards, so I use an external. Also, from what I read up on your particular laptop, it's not exactly cutting edge. So, it'll be handy to have an external keyboard for when you get a new computer or new laptop one day.

Comment: Well my hands and fingers have got quite used to working with this keyboard, installed within the laptop. Getting used to an external keyboard will certainly take some time. :) Still if I were to get one, what model/brand would you recommend me?

Comment: I'd prefer a smaller one, the same size as the one that sits in my 15 inches laptop...

Comment: you know, with only 1key that isn't working, you probably don't have too much to worry about. For what it's worth, my own personal keyboard that I've come to love is the microsoft wireless keyboard 3000 v2.0 , which is actually pretty good for laptops because it's wireless. As smaller keyboards go, tell me where you reside-- I can do a little hunting for you, but if you're not in the USA, then me referring to you USA-webstores won't do you much good.

Comment: Sorry for a really late reply, I have an update on the issue in question. I upgraded to Windows 10 as I said I was gonna do in the previous posts, so what happened after the upgrade was that the windows updated my touchpad drivers with - "lenovo pointing device 19.9.0.5", software, and to my disbelief the Q started working with Rshift. :) There is however a new problem, it's to do with keyboard or PC inputting special character in the middle of certain words when I type really fast. I'll try to demonstrate that with the following words - "no-", "c\o". You see '-' after no and '/' between co

Comment: ,there was anoter word in between which "@" was inserted on it's own. Now interestingly it doesn't happen if I type slowly, only when I'm typing really fast. :) Could it be a driver's bug? And more importantly can we at least say that my keyboard is not faulty afterall Q has started working with the rshift.

Comment: Actually I just noticed Windows has installed some driver named - Chicony - Keyboard - Lenovo ThinkPad PS2/Keyboard. So as opposed to what I mention earlier that the Q started working as a result of some touchpad driver update, I think the change is down to this driver update. In any case, I'm certainly not happy with it, it might have made my Q key to work again, but it's come at an annoying cost with keyboard now having a mind of its down, putting special character in between words lol

Answer (score 0):

The fault is with your keyboard.

What the actual fault is, we can't tell without looking at it, but as per my question in the comments on your OP, I asked if you could try another keyboard. Since the USB keyboard works fine, it shows the fault is not software but in fact hardware.

I would simply use <kbd>left shift</kbd>, an external keyboard or you could *try* and use a tool like Auto Hot Key to map the <kbd>right shift</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> combination to the <kbd>left shift</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd>!

Something like

```
RShift & q::
Send {LShift}+q
return
```

Comment: Yeah you're probably right there, but it's strange for only one key to not be working and that too only in a combination with another key.

Comment: I don't think mapping the rShift to left would be a good move as the former works fine with other keys except just for q. I'll keep the settings as they're and use lShift for capital q wherever need be.

Comment: That's no problem. Since I don't know much about keyboard mapping, your post has made me rather curious about it, would mapping the rshift to lshift for q combination make the rshift work as if it were the lshift?

Comment: I downloaded Windows Hot key commander as suggested in another answer. Would that work for mapping keys?

Comment: A hardware fault means RShift+q wouldn't register at all and the computer does not receive the key stroke, why would it magically work with autohotkey then? On the other hand, if it works(very unlikely) then its a software issue.

Comment: But rShift isn't totally impaired hardware or software wise, so I think it might work in my case.

Comment: I'm really new to this, could anyone provide with a detailed step-by-step instructions on how to do key-mapping?